# Single id with different error classes

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with id (`form_select`) which has 2 error classes (`errorIdentification` and `errorIdentification1`).

```
$('#form_select').validate({
  rules: {
    'user_name' : {
       required: true
       },
    'password'   : {
       required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    'user_name' : {
       required: 'From date is required!'
      },
    'password'   : {
       required: 'To date is required!'
      }
  },
  errorClass: **'errorIdentification'**,
  errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
  err.insertBefore(element);
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  form.submit();
  }
});


$('#form_select').validate({
  rules: {
    'from' : {
       required: true
       },
    'to'   : {
       required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    'from' : {
       required: 'From date is required!'
      },
    'to'   : {
       required: 'To date is required!'
      }
  },
  errorClass: **'errorIdentification1'**,
  errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
  err.insertBefore(element);
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  form.submit();
  }
});
```

The problem is on validating the form, all the fields(username, password, from and to) are getting the same  errorClass `errorIdentification` which is first error class for(user name and password)

How can I implement this with different error classes?

Comment: Why do you need a separate class? You can target a particular field by adding a class on the field. So you could have something like `.errorIdentification.field-username` and `.errorIdentification.field-from`.

Comment: @Michael- I need different error classes for somewhat font adjustments.

Comment: If that's the case, see my comment above. You don't really need the separate class. You can just target the fields individually. Or you could add a container element around groups of fields which should be styled similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your second form script like;

```
$('#form_select').validate({
  rules: {
    'from' : {
       required: true
       },
    'to'   : {
       required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    'from' : {
       required: 'From date is required!'
      },
    'to'   : {
       required: 'To date is required!'
      }
  },
  errorClass: **'errorIdentification1'**,
  errorPlacement: function(err, element) {
  err.insertBefore(element);
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry. I forgot to change that. The issue is not because of that.